# How to read the parent name of content type

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, document-library, content-type, sharepoint-on-prem

I want to read the document library content type parent name. Below is the code I used. I am not getting any values in that. Can someone suggest on this?

```
$contentTypes = $ctx.web.contenttypes  
$ctx.load($contentTypes)  
$ctx.executeQuery()
$ctx.Dispose()
foreach($ct in $contentTypes)
{  
    write-host $ct.Name  
    Write-Host $ct.DocumentTemplate
    Write-Host $ct.DocumentTemplateUrl
    Write-Host $ct.Group
    Write-Host $ct.Description
    Write-Host $ct.Parent.Parent.Name
    Write-Host $ct.Id
```

Have tried:

```
$ct.Parent
$ct.Parent.Name
$ct.Parent.Parent.Name
```

Comment: Try using `$ct.Parent.Name` and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: it is not working .. I have tried multiple way

Comment: Can you please mention the various ways you tried in your question? that will be helpful for other users to answer your question correctly.

Comment: $ct.Parent, $ct.Parent.Name, $ct.Parent.Parent.Name

Comment: Are you able to get other properties like content type Name, Id? Check [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31151.sharepoint-online-content-types-in-powershell-get.aspx) article if it helps you.

Comment: yes all i am able to get.. for ex document library, the parent name is document that is not coming

Comment: Parent: Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ContentType final outcome

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110091/discussion-between-liz-and-ganesh-sanap).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this script:

```
$Web = Get-SPWeb "http://sp"

$cts=$Web.ContentTypes
foreach($ct in $cts)
{
Write-Host $ct.get_Name()
Write-Host $ct.get_Parent().Name
Write-Host "--------------------"
}
```

Test result:

[image]

**Updated**

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"



$webURL="http://sp"
$ctx= New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($webURL)

try{
    $web = $ctx.web
    
    $cts=$web.ContentTypes
    $ctx.Load($web)
    $ctx.Load($cts)
    $ctx.executeQuery()
    foreach($ct in $cts)
{
$ctx.Load($ct.Parent)
    $ctx.executeQuery()
Write-Host $ct.get_Name()
Write-Host $ct.get_Parent().Name
Write-Host "--------------------"
}
}
catch{
    write-host "$($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor red
}
```

New test result:

[image]

Comment: I want it in Pnp or CSOM Powershell.. can u suggest in that

Comment: check the update

Comment: Thank you saved the day